# SQL INSERT INTO statement.. Error, I am very new to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, where-clause

I've searched everywhere for an answer and can't find anyone so I have resorted to making my own post. This is for a university assignment. I am using HeidiSQL.

This is my code

```
INSERT INTO 
loan(patronCode,bookCode,loanDate,dueDate)
VALUES 
(
SELECT
    patron.patronCode
WHERE
    patron.fname='Jacob' AND patron.lname='Simmons', 
SELECT
    book.bookCode
WHERE
    book.bookTitle='The Agony And The Empathy',
'2014-09-10',
'2014-10-01'
),
(
SELECT
    patron.patronCode
WHERE
    patron.fname='Jacob' AND patron.lname='Simmons', 
SELECT
    book.bookCode
WHERE
    book.bookTitle='Kevin Rudd: The Biography',
'2014-09-10',
'2014-10-01'
)
FROM

loan
INNER JOIN patron 
  ON loan.patronCode=patron.patronCode
INNER JOIN book
 ON loan.bookCode=book.bookCode;
```

This is my error message:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL synstax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT patron.patronCode
>   WHERE
>   patron.fname='Jacob' AND patron.lname='Si' at line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An insert statement needs to take the form of:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(FIELDNAME1, FIELDNAME2...)
VALUES('HARDCODED_VALUE1', 'HARDCODED_VALUE2'...)
```

You have mixed this with the logic of an insert with a select statement. Which looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(FIELDNAME1, FIELDNAME2...)
SELECT Column1, Column2...
FROM TABLENAME
```

You have 2 different inserts here.  Perhaps they could be combined with a bit more information.  Also, you dont indicate how `patron` and `book` are joined, probably they arent, so I've left the join out.

Here is the first one, the second can be patterned after it.

```
INSERT INTO loan(patronCode,bookCode,loanDate,dueDate)
SELECT patron.patronCode,book.bookCode,'2014-09-10','2014-10-01'
FROM patron, book
WHERE
  patron.fname='Jacob' AND patron.lname='Simmons'
  and book.bookTitle='The Agony And The Empathy'
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. clearly I have a lot to learn about SQL because I don't really understand why that works without the inner join statements.

Comment: SQL89 syntax (the old style) works this way, the join happens in the `where` portion.  SQL92 introduced the `inner join` syntax.  The problem that you will have with this is if you have more than one patron named Jacob Simmons, or more than one book called "The Agony and the Empathy", then it will insert 2 records into your loan table.  So make sure your `where` criteria is tight enough to give you the correct number of results.  (just run the select portion first to make sure thats what you want to insert)

Comment: To clarify, you are simply saying, give me everything from the patron table and join it on everything in the book table that match these criteria.  So its easy to get more than you want if there is not a matching ID like you have in loan.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the SELECT statement's syntax will be:

```
SELECT patronCode FROM tablename WHERE ....
```

Comment: There is quite a bit more wrong with OP's statement that this.

Comment: I'm on mobile so just glanced and read the error statement. Let me see what else is wrong now.